# Alias c++ template in a class

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I am implementing a member function of a class which must be templated.

```
class Foo {

  template <typename T>
  void do(templated_class<T> in);
};

template <typename T>
void Foo::do(templated_class<T> in) { 
  // definition starts here.
}
```

Is there any easy way to alias the template such that I don't have to write `template <typename T>` each time I put something to do with the class `templated_class`? For example, I am imaging if the following is possible.

```
class Foo {
  template <typename T>
  using templated_class_t = templated_class<T>;

  void (templated_class_t in);
};

void Foo::do(templated_class_t in) {
   // definition starts here.
}
```

Apparently compiler complains about this.

Comment: How often do you really need this? With a decent auto completer, this is just a couple of keystrokes and certainly the clearest way.

Comment: If you just want straight name replacement you could use a macro: `#define templated_class_t templated_class<T>`, i don't know what this gains, seems less clear and just as hard to type.

Comment: @Ben It won't work since `Foo::do` is anyway a template function and hence must be defined as `template <typename T> void Foo::do(templated_class_t in) {...}`

Comment: Eventually `do` is a keyword and nothing is gonna work anyway.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov There are ways around this: `#define templated_definition ( function_name ) template <typename T>
function_name(templated_class<T> ` Then you would use it like: `templated_defintion ( void Foo::do ) in, ...)`. Again, not as good as just writing what you mean ...

Answer (score 0):

If most of `Foo`'s member function are templated on the same parameter, just make `Foo` a class template. Furthermore, you can put the definitions all in-class and save some code duplication.

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
    do_fun(template_class<T> in)
    {
        // put definition in-class
    }
};
```

Otherwise (only `do_fun` is a member template) just put that definition in-class

```
class Foo
{
    template<class T>
    do_fun(template_class<T> in)
    {
        // put definition in-class
    }
};
```